# Downloading a file greater than 20 MB using JSInterop call to a javascript causes a browser disconnection error

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor

In our server side blazor application, we have an option to download files  using javascript.  The problem is that when I try to download a file greater than 20 MB, the connection gets closed and the downloading process is interrupted.

And the browser displays a message saying:

Attempting to reconnect to the server...

And the browser console shows the error:

blazor.server.js:1 [2019-10-17T22:47:31.704Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ().'.

Is there a way to allow big files to be downloaded ?

Is there some timeout, that I need to increase in order to download files with a size larger than 20 MB ?

I tried this without any improvement:

services.AddServerSideBlazor(
                options => options.JSInteropDefaultCallTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

The javascript is:

```
function saveAsFile(filename, base64) {
    var array = Base64Binary.decode(base64);
    let blob = new Blob([array], {
        type: 'application/octet-stream'
    });

    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, name);
    } else {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = filename;
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = filename;
    link.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Needed for Firefox
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

}

And the javascript is called as:

```
public static ValueTask<object> SaveAs(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, string filename, byte[] data) => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("saveAsFile", filename, Convert.ToBase64String(data));
```

My expectation is to allow our users to download files up to 150 MB without the browser being disconnected.

Comment: sounds like a timeout setting needs increasing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the message buffer size exceeded, you could set the buffer size using the below configuration.

```
endpoints.MapHub<ComponentHub>(
            ComponentHub.DefaultPath,
            o =>
            {
                o.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = 102400000; // larger size
                o.TransportMaxBufferSize = 102400000; // larger size
            })
```

Reference: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9570#issuecomment-488649334